# Installing BCP without installing SQL Server in client machine?

Tags: .net, sql-server, bcp

I export data from database using the `BCP` utility, I want to install bcp in client machine. I don't want to install SQL Server 2008 in client machine.

Is their any minimal installers available to install just bcp?

This is urgent task. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use one of the [SQL Server distributable packages](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16978) to stay within licensing terms.
Specifically "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Command Line Utilities"

Note: copying bcp.exe by itself will not work

Edit: latest download link: [SQL Server distributable packages](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6c3e9ef-ba29-4a43-8d69-a2bed18fe73c)

Edit: an even later download link:  [SQL Server 2008R2 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978)

Comment: I Installed --> sqlncli.msi (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client )
SqlCmdLnUtils.msi (Command Line Utils), Even I can not able to use bcp

Comment: @gpn : I Solved the problem by Setting Up Path (In Environmental Variable). thanks

Comment: @Ramakrishnan: this is often caused by an old install of SQL Server tools which has changed PATH previously

Comment: @gbn Just stumbled across your answer.  Second link is broken.  +1 for general awesomeness.

Answer (score 9):

**2015** - Installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

I needed the ODBC driver installed first...

**Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=36434

**Microsoft® Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=36433

p.s.
In case you're reading this post and the year is > 2015, use the search to find a similar download:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/search/DownloadResults.aspx?q=Microsoft%20Command%20Line%20Utilities

Comment: I like the link to the search. I did, however, change the search term to `microsoft sql server feature pack`, as the results are named after a SQL Server version, which is more user friendly. The first links are only relevant for SQL Server 2014, and the search was useful for me to find older versions as well. Thanks.

Comment: If you use chocolatey, there is also a [sqlserver-cmdlineutils package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/sqlserver-cmdlineutils) available that includes bcp and takes care of all the dependencies.  `choco install sqlserver-cmdlineutils`

Answer (score 3):

BCP comes with "Command Line Utilities" package. You need to install "ODBC driver" first. Sending you the links for download

[Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#version-17) - [Direct Download Link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/f/f/6ffefc73-39ab-4cc0-bb7c-4093d64c2669/en-US/17.10.3.1/x64/msodbcsql.msi)

[Microsoft Command Line Utilities 15 for SQL Server (x64)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16#download-and-install-sqlcmd) - [Direct Download Link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/a/a/4/aa47b3b0-9f67-441d-8b00-e74cd845ea9f/EN/x64/MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi)

Answer (score 2):

well,just put the file below into **c:/windows/**

```
sqlncli.dll
bcp.exe
bcp.rll
```

i tested on windows xp with which the 3 files come from sql server 2005 client