# Minimum requirements to run Sql Server BCP.exe utility

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am working with a client who needs to do a data import to a remote SQL Server (2008) instance.  The machine that the import will be done from cannot have SQL Server installed on it.  Can the BCP.exe utility run without a SQL Server install?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing BCP with installing SQL Server in client machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295049/installing-bcp-with-installing-sql-server-in-client-machine)

Answer (score 1):

BCP relies on some basic DLLs. Why don't you try installing client tools and run BCP from there. It will be a pretty clean server without SQL installed.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1807/sql-server-2008-client-tools-installation/

Answer (score 1):

I got a great answer over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

[Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5541/minimum-requirements-to-run-sql-server-bcp-exe-utility)

Answer (score 0):

**2015** - Installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

I needed the ODBC driver installed first...

**Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=36434

**Microsoft® Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=36433

p.s. In case you're reading this post and the year is > 2015, use the search to find a similar download:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/search/DownloadResults.aspx?q=Microsoft%20Command%20Line%20Utilities